# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un sitio que sea visible para móviles?

Tags: javascript, android, php, .htaccess

Cómo puedo hacer un sitio que sólo sea visible para móviles y que sólo se pueda entrar vía móvil, que no se pueda entrar vía pc. Y también que sólo a partir de la ver 4 o superior de android se permita entrar. O sea, básicamente como la funcionalidad de una aplicación android que sólo esté disponible para esas versiones android.

¿Se puede lograr con htaccess, php o javascript?

¿Cómo podría utilizar esta librería http://mobiledetect.net para lograrlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería mobiledetect para `PHP`, que tú mismo citas, de esta manera:

```
<?php

    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php'; // Tu ruta al fichero aquí
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect; // Instanciamos la clase


    if (!$detect->isMobile()) { // No permitir acceso si no es un dispositivo móvil (Tablet o móvil)
         // Redireccionar error 4xx: acceso no permitido.
    }

    // Quizás quieras prohibir el acceso también a tablets
    if ($detect->isMobile() && $detect->isTablet()){
         // Redireccionar error 4xx: acceso no permitido.
    }

    // No permitir acceso a SO distinto de Android:
    if(!$detect->isAndroidOS() ) {
         // Redireccionar error 4xx: acceso no permitido.
    }

    // No permitir acceso a versiones android menores de 4.0
    if ($detect->version('Android') < 4) {
         // Redireccionar error 4xx: acceso no permitido.
    }
```

Básicamente esto es todo lo que necesitas. Obviamente, puedes combinar las condiciones de estos if y hacer todas las comprobaciones en un único paso, lo he puesto así para que sea más claro.

Comment: muchas gracias, la verdad no tenia ni idea de como se usaba. xD

Comment: Creo que conviene comentar que un usuario puede cambiar facilmente el user-agent de su navegador para engañar a la librería de detección.

Comment: @gontrollez, ciertamente, es posible. Pero basándonos en eso, no habría manera 100% segura de detectar dispositivos móviles en el servidor. Otras medidas como la comprobación por IP o medidas en la lado cliente, como comprobar la resolución también pueden ser burladas fácilmente. Esta forma es sencilla y versátil, siempre y cuando confíes en que el usuario no trama nada raro.

Comment: Si. En realidad el comentario lo tendría que haber escrito en la pregunta, no en tu respuesta, ya que lo que pretendía era que no piense que puede usar este mecanismo como medida de seguridad o similar. De hecho tengo curiosidad por saber en qué caso este tipo de restricción tiene sentido. Si es para acceder desde dentro de un app, entonces debe implementarse un mecanismo de seguridad real.

Answer (score 1):

Detectar el agente de usuario (`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`) no es 100% fiable, es una cadena que construye el navegador, y como tal puede cambiarse.

Una extensión (por ejemplo) para Firefox que lo permite es: http://mybrowseraddon.com/useragent-switcher.html

Disculpad que lo ponga como respuesta, todavía no puedo poner comentarios.

Una alternativa sería enviar como parte de la petición información que indique en que plataforma se generó; como con un parámetro de la URL.

Answer (score 0):

Con PHP y el user agent del navegador puedes saber la versión, otro detalle importante seria los navegadores que quieres permitir, si solo es android, en el user agent de chrome te viene la versión de android utilizada.
Con esto cuando detectes una version no compatible simplemente puedes mostrar un mensaje o redireccionar al usuario.

En PHP seria:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
//Te devolvera algo como:
//Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; XT1068 Build/LXB22.99-16.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.91 Mobile Safari/537.36|
```

En JS seria:

```js
alert("Datos de tu navegador: " + navigator.userAgent)
```

Comment: si ya tenia en mente eso, pero como podria obtener solo datos específicos como la versión y el dispositivo. ¿que regex podria usar para tomar solo esos datos? digamos que lo que me muestras sobre el dispositivo solo quiero tomar esto `Android 5.0.2`

Comment: mira buscando por google, encontré esta librería http://mobiledetect.net pero no se como utilizarla para lograr lo que quiero.